# URL with parameters show error 404 Laravel

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-routing

I already checked many solved questions about the same theme, but any of them solved my problem. For example, if I remove the parameter in the URL, all runs well, but with the parameter, the system shows error 404.

**Routes**

```
// Planes
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('planes', ['as' => 'planes.index', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PlanController@index']);
    Route::post('guardar_plan', ['as' => 'planes.guardar', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PlanController@guardar_plan']);
    Route::post('eliminar_plan', ['as' => 'planes.eliminar', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PlanController@eliminar_plan']);
    Route::post('datos_plan', ['as' => 'planes.datos', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PlanController@datos_plan']);
    Route::post('editar_plan', ['as' => 'planes.editar', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PlanController@editar_plan']);
});

// Complejos
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('nuevo_complejo', ['as' => 'complejo.nuevo', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ComplejoController@nuevo']);
    Route::get('lista_complejos', ['as' => 'complejo.lista', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ComplejoController@lista']);
    Route::get('ver_complejo\{id}', ['as' => 'ver_complejo', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ComplejoController@ver_complejo']);
    Route::post('guardar_nuevo_complejo', ['as' => 'complejo.guardar', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ComplejoController@guardar_nuevo_complejo']);
});

// Ejemplares
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('nuevo_ejemplar', ['as' => 'ejemplar.nuevo', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\EjemplarController@nuevo']);
    Route::get('lista_ejemplares', ['as' => 'ejemplar.lista', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\EjemplarController@lista']);
    Route::get('ver_ejemplar', ['as' => 'ver_ejemplar', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\EjemplarController@ver_ejemplar']);
    Route::get('nuevo_pa', ['as' => 'ejemplar.nuevopa', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\EjemplarController@nuevo_pa']);
    Route::post('guardar_ejemplar', ['as' => 'ejemplar.guardar', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\EjemplarController@guardar_ejemplar']);
});

// Cirugias
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('nueva_cirugia', ['as' => 'cirugia.nueva', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\CirugiasController@nueva']);
    Route::get('formato_cirugia', ['as' => 'cirugia.formato', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\CirugiasController@formato_cirugia']);
});
```

**ComplejoController**

```
public function ver_complejo ($id) 
{
    return view('superadministrador.ver_complejo',['planes' => Planes::all()]);
}
```

The problematic URL is this:

```
Route::get('ver_complejo\{id}', ['as' => 'ver_complejo','uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ComplejoController@ver_complejo']);
```

What's the problem?

Comment: "*if i remove the parameter in the url all runs well, but with the parameter the systems shows error 404*" - you did not show us the actual URL you are visiting. One observation: is the backslash in `ver_complejo\{id}` a typo here on SO, or are you really using that?  You probably mean `/`, I think.

Comment: You're right, i solve the problem using / instead of \, thanks.